# Can we make Label bold in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Item: Display Only used in a page of Oracle Apex App v4.1, Can I make the Label Bold.
Please help me with a quick way to do so.
Also if I can not make it as Bold, do we have other way to fulfill the requirement.
[![trying to make Label as Bold][1]][1]
Regards,
Anshul Ayushya

Comment: What version of apex are you on and do you want to make just one label bold or all labels in the application ?

Comment: using 4.1 and wanted to bold one label, through html tags I did.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a 4.x version installed anymore to test. You could put it in the label or use css to style it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple option is to use *bold* HTML tags. Into the "Label" item property put

```
<b>Employee name</b>
```

When you run the page, it'll be displayed bold: **Employee name**

Comment: Hay Many Thanks for help. Much appreciated.